# Special HTML / CSS Accordion Actions

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a page that has separate styling from the rest of my site. So I'm doing all the HTML and CSS within that page.  Currently I am trying to make a semi-complex (at least for me) accordion.  This is how I would like it to work:

- Hover to expand (Got that far)
- Click to to keep open until another slide is clicked
- Have a header that is part of the main accordion but not affected by the hovers and clicks

I also plan on adding in images as well as possibly additional accordions within.  The internal accordions would be horizontal and the main ones are vertical.

I've also managed to muk this up a bit.  I can't for the life of me flatten all the corners out so they arn't round.

*Keep in mind I don't know THAT much about html and CSS.  Most of what I have was either googled, guessed, or prior knowledge.  I really do appreciate any help I can get.*

### **CSS**

```
    <style>

/*------------------------------------*\
    ACCORDION
\*------------------------------------*/

.accordion{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    background:transparent;

    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.accordion li{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:250px;
    -moz-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay:0.15s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.15s;
    -o-transition-delay:0.15s;
    transition-delay:0.15s;
}
.accordion li:first-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0 0 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0 0 0px;
    -o-border-radius:0px 0 0 0px;
    border-radius:0px 0 0 0px;
}
.accordion li:last-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:0 0px 0px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0px 0px 0;
    -o-border-radius:0 0px 0px 0;
    border-radius:0 0px 0px 0;
}
.accordion div{
    padding:10px;
}
.accordion:hover li{
    width:10%;
}
.accordion li:hover{
    width:30%;
}
.slide-01  { background:white; color:#333; text-shadow:none; }
.slide-02  { background:white; color:#333; text-shadow:none; }
.slide-03  { background:white; color:#333; text-shadow:none; }
.slide-04  { background:white; color:#333; text-shadow:none; }
.slide-05  { background:white; color:#333; text-shadow:none; }

/*------------------------------------*\
    VERTICAL
\*------------------------------------*/
#vertical{
    height:600px;
}
#vertical li{
    float:none;
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
#vertical li:first-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    -o-border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
#vertical li:last-of-type{
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    -o-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}
#vertical:hover li{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
#vertical li:hover{
    height:30%;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<ul class="accordion" id="vertical">
  <li class="slide-01">
    <div>
      <h2>» Slide one</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-02">
    <div>
      <h2>» Slide two</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-03">
    <div>
      <h2>» Slide three</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="slide-04">
    <div>
      <h2>» Slide four</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="slide-05">
    <div>
      <h2>» Slide Five</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So are you specifically asking the community _how to flatten all the corners_? Keep in mind SO is not a code review forum.

Comment: "Click to to keep open..." you will require the use of javascript here, not just html and css

Comment: I mean eventually I could figure that out.  I am trying to figure out how to do the things I listed in the bullets.
I prob should have actually asked the question ha!

Comment: @zgood Is it possible to put JavaScript in the same sheet as the HTML and the CSS?  I haven't used it before.

Comment: @JWaggz yes sir. your javascript would be inside `<script>` tags on your page

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you calling the javascript to create the actions.

Please look at this link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125398/Java-Accordion-Menu-Visual-Effects-and-Customizati

as for your rounded corners, you must remove the following code from the CSS file

```
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
```

that is what rounds the corners of elements.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah.. that looks like a very useful resource. I appreciate it.  

I didn't even try removing that part of the code. I changed the radius back and forth but never just removed it.